# OpenShift + HAProxy too many sessions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openshift, haproxy

I am developing an application using Kraken.js and to manage the sessions I decided to use: connect-mongo.

I have a setup like this:

```
'use strict';

var session = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

module.exports = function SessionLib(opts) {
  return session({
    secret: opts.secret,
    resave: opts.resave,
    saveUninitialized: opts.saveUninitialized,
    store: new MongoStore({
      url: opts.url,
      ttl: opts.ttl
    })
  });
};
```

I deployment the app in OpenShift with the option of auto-scaling, OpenShift are using HAProxy for auto scaling but this is causing me an error generating too many sessions in my MongoDB (About 250,000 in last weekend).

There is the possibility of not keeping HAProxy sessions?

Comment: Did you get it solved ? I'm experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround:

Why don't you add a TTL index on you database for those session documents? You can add such indexes where you mark one field a TTL document should have, so every document having that field in a collection, will be removed after it's TTL expires

Comment: In fact I use connect-mongo and have set a TTL index for each session, except that the only problem is that many sessions are created and begins to occupy much space in my database.

Comment: Well, if you are supporting sessions and already have a TTL, why don't you make that TTL shorter? Hmm maybe you could still be on time to make your application a bit stateless? Use JWT and use some Redis based cache?

Comment: I don't think writing sessions to MongoDB is the best though. Redis or something will always be faster :)

Comment: Redis is definitely faster and have already implemented sessions using Redis just too fast also have many sessions, 100Mb in a week, ~ 485k sessions...

Comment: Not really, 90-95% of those sessions is creating the OpenShift HAProxy server, which can scale the application as needed...